# perl eval with back quote

Tags: python, perl, eval

I was converting a perl script into python and then I found this function which I couldn't understand.

```
sub set_xyz_hash {
    %xyz = ();
    $_ = join(' ', map { my $a = $_; $a =~ s/\'/\'\"\'\"\'/g; "'$a'" } @ARGV);
    eval `XYZ_ARG0='$0' NZENV_OUTPUT='-a -p xyz' xyz $_`;
}
```

since my knowledge in perl is very limited, I couldn't understand **'eval'** used in this function. can someone please help me here?

**note, eval is used wth ` (back quote).**

Comment: Try to firstly ***print*** the statement instead of (or in addition to) eval'ing it, i.e. `print "XYZ_ARG0='$0' NZENV_OUTPUT='-a -p xyz' xyz $_", "\n";`. So you can see what actually gets executed. The 'eval' then executes the output of that very command as Perl code.

Comment: Note that you must trust the command that's run; this is very risky from some points of view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backticks run an external command and return the output:

```
my $result = `ls -l`;
print $result;
```

Your `eval` line is processed exactly the same way:

```
my $result = `XYZ_ARG0='$0' NZENV_OUTPUT='-a -p xyz' xyz $_`;
eval $result;
```

It's basically fetching some Perl source from the output of the called script and runs it.

Comment: I have marked it as answer. one last doubt on this item, how $0 in single quotes will behave inside back quotes?

Comment: You've to read the line like a compiler: There is no *$0 in single quotes*, there is a `$0` in backticks with some other chars. Variables in backticks are replaced, so $0 will become the current process title. Try `print \`echo '$0'\`;`. `print` and `echo` are very powerful debug and learning tools :)